# Meteor Autoform linked inputs?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I'm just trying to figure out what would be the most elegant way to solve following problem with meteor autoform and collection2:

I created a signup form which allows to select countries and states. Of course the selectable states should change according to the country selected. Is there a 'native' autoform approach to this or do i have to do it with events and conditional rendering?

Kind Regards and thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685163/meteor-autoform-how-to-update-select-options-based-on-another-control